# php check if file_exists() with htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm using htacces mod_rewrite to rewrite my websites URLs, for example:

```
/dir/file.php
/dir/file_example.php
/dir/file2.php?id=test
```

become

```
/dir/file
/dir/file-example
/dir/file2-test
```

All ok. Now I have a PHP script to do certain redirect, but before of the redirect I would like to check if the file (or url) exist:

```
if(file_exists("/dir/file2-test")){ // redirect on page
}else{ // redirect on index
```

But file_exists() return false in this case.

There is another way to check if these pages/url (file2-test, file-example, etc) exists via php?

*PS: Due the complexity of my htaccess rules I don't have the possibility to just append ".php" at the end.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **could** check, whether the URL does exist via actually calling it, but at the cost of doing a real http request with all the server load and latency caused by this.

```
$file = 'http://www.domain.com/dir/file2-test';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php#75064

I would not recommend this at all.

I don't see any real chance to probe the RewriteEngine logic from php, so I suggest to integrate your whole rewrite logic either in htaccess or php.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to check the **absolute path**, then you have to add the file extension (for files):

```
file_exists( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dir/file2-test.php') // check php file
file_exists( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dir/file2-test')     // check directory
```

or, maybe better:

```
file_exists( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI"].".php") // check php file
file_exists( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI"])        // check directory
```

but — to work also with segments and/or queries — you should use `parse_url`:

```
$uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
file_exists( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$uri['path'].".php") // check php file
file_exists( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$uri['path'])        // check directory
```

#### Edit:

> Due the complexity of my htaccess rules I don't have the possibility to just append ".php" at the end.

Try `glob()`:

```
$uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
$files = glob( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$uri['path'].'*' );
```

Now in `$files` you will have **all** file starting with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$uri['path']`

---

- Read mored about [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url)
- Read mored about [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to check if the mod_rewrited URL exists. I cannot add .php

Comment: @ipel please also note that if your ‘complexity’  reside in queries (`?...`), `parse_url` will resolve it